# Riesz inequality

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $p>2$ and $$\|b\|^p_p:=\int_0^{2\pi} |b(e^{it})|^p dt.$$
Assume that $a$ is a bounded holomorphic on the unit disk and assume that $a(0)=0$.
What is the best constant $C_p$ in the inequality $$\|a\|_p\le C_p \|\Re(a)\|_p?$$

Comment: Did you write $a$ for $b$ or vice-versa?

Comment: @Brendan McKay $b$ could be $a$ and $\Re (a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The sharp constant is $C_p = 1/\cos\pi/(2p')$, where $p'=p/(p-1)$.